# SSAS Process Dimensions Error

Tags: ssas, business-intelligence, olap-cube, sql-server-2012-datatools

I'm trying to deploy my SSAS project but I keep getting this error that makes no sense to me?

```
Error   5   Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.        0   0   

Error   6   The datasource, 'Adventure Works DW2012', contains an ImpersonationMode that is not supported for processing operations.        0   0   

Error   7   Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Adventure Works DW2012', Name of 'Adventure Works DW2012'.      0   0   

Error   8   Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the dimension, with the ID of 'Dim Organization', Name of 'Dim Organization' was being processed.        0   0   

Error   9   Errors in the OLAP storage engine: An error occurred while the 'Organization Name' attribute of the 'Dim Organization' dimension from the 'CubeDemo06' database was being processed.        0   0   

Error   10  Server: The current operation was cancelled because another operation in the transaction failed.        0   0
```

Maybe the "ImpersonationMode" has to do with login credentials? I'm using "use current user", maybe that could be the problem? How do you change that now? The other errors are strange since everything should work according to this tutorial: https://www.accelebrate.com/library/tutorials/ssas-2008

Comment: The other errors are just results of the initial impersonation mode error. Try this:  double-click the data source to open the data source designer box and switch to Impersonation Information page, then select "Use the service account" or "Inherit" option for your data source impersonation.

Comment: Tested both Service Account and Inherit and it gave me another type of error:

Error 5 Internal error: The operation terminated unsuccessfully.  0 0 
Error 6 OLE DB error: OLE DB or ODBC error: Login failed for user 'NT Service\MSSQLServerOLAPService'.; 28000.  0 0 
Error 7 Errors in the high-level relational engine. A connection could not be made to the data source with the DataSourceID of 'Adventure Works DW2012', Name of 'Adventure Works DW2012'.  0 0

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved by using Windows Credentials!

Answer (score 1):

Go to the data source and select service account option as below
[image]